# iPython console in Spyder IDE hangs on any code execution

Tags: python, console, spyder

Pretty much what the title says - no matter what I run, even if it's just a print("hello") it will get stuck executing it.

I'm using the most recent Spyder version, updated today, I turned off my antivirus, started as administrator, started from anaconda prompt, tried to run the file, run a cell, run a selection - it always gets stuck.

The only way I managed to run some code was to first run Debug then exit Debug. After that, I could execute everything normally, but only until I restarted Spyder. Now not even the Debug trick will work.

It's a new PC with Windows 10. I also use Avira and Malwarebytes, but I turned them off while testing this.

I really have no clue what to do, I spent a bunch of time Googling it and found some people with similar issues but none of them got answers. It doesn't even print an error I could look up...

Answer (score 3):

I've just run into the same issue on a new computer (spyder 5.0.5, spyder-kernels 2.0.5, ipython 7.27.0). Trying to run a file within the current IPython console causes the console to hang.

The workaround I found is to change the run configuration to "execute in a dedicated console".